# Однородные и неоднородные обстоятельства

Tags: обстоятельство

Kак здесь правильно расставить запятые:

*В 1960 году, среди металлического хлама, в мастерской тепловых сетей, в г. Кемерово («Кузбассэнерго»), я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, запятые не нужны. Здесь нет ни однородных членов, ни уточнений, которые требуют постановки запятой.

**В 1960 году среди металлического хлама в мастерской тепловых сетей в г. Кемерово («Кузбассэнерго») я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную.**

Дополнение

Непонятнo, что такое тепловые сети и "Кузбассэнерго" в этом предложении. Например, если "Тепловые сети" - название предприятия, входящего в объединение "Кузбассэнерго", то я бы сказал так:

**В 1960 году среди металлического хлама в мастерской "Тепловых сетей" («Кузбассэнерго», г. Кемерово) я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную.**

Вам нужно выяснить, как правильно пишутся названия упоминаемых предприятий.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, похоже, так и есть...

Answer (score 3):

Я бы оставила предложение без изменений:

В 1960 году, **среди металлического хлама, в мастерской тепловых сетей, в г. Кемерово («Кузбассэнерго»),** я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную.

Все выделенные обстоятельства **уточняют условия находки**, поэтому  уточняющий обособленный ряд обстоятельств считается однородным (хотя по смыслу обстоятельства  неоднородные), в этом случае обстоятельственные признаки считаются сближенными в конкретной ситуации.

Обратим также внимание, что прочитать 4 неоднородных обстоятельства подряд (без пауз) довольно затруднительно.

Comment: Если обстоятельства можно сближать по общему признаку, то, возможно, запятые и оправданны... Хотя, видимо, строго по правилам запятые и не нужны... Получается, они здесь больше авторские?..

Comment: Нет, здесь всё по правилам. У Розенталя  говорится, что  прилагательные могут объединяться общим признаком в условиях контекста: (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.): В небе таяло одно маленькое, золотистое облачко (М. Г.) — внешний вид; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Comment: Но то же самое можно отнести и к однородным обстоятельствам. Про уточняющие обстоятельства у Розенталя вот что сказано: Нередко уточняющие обстоятельства места выстраиваются в ряд, образуют цепочку:Тут же, возле амбара, прямо на снегу, раздевались (Ш.).                                             http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Comment: Может я бы и согласился с Вами, Arina, но после некоторой престановки этих обстоятельств или при разделении их, скажем,  на три более-менее связанные группы. А так получается "куча мала" :)) Особенно режет глаз смешение года и хлама: "в 1960 году, среди металлического хлама".

Comment: У меня один аргумент: все эти четыре обстоятельства  подряд просто невозможно прочитать в устной речи и трудно понять в письменном варианте, поэтому на какие-то группы делить надо. А то, что разные по темам обстоятельства расположены рядом, то это вопрос к автору. Меня это, кстати, не напрягает, даже интригующе звучит, художественно.

Comment: @Sharon  Вам плюс! Мне тоже хочется разделить обстоятельства, но объединить 2-е и 3-е, а 4-е взять в скобки:  _В 1960 году, среди металлического хлама в мастерской тепловых сетей («Кузбассэнерго», г. Кемерово), я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную._

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Спасибо, Александр. Я бы сейчас написала так:В 1960 году, среди металлического хлама, в мастерской тепловых сетей в г. Кемерово («Кузбассэнерго»), я обнаружил необычную задвижку – сварную. Получаются 3 выделенные координаты (когда, при каких обстоятельствах, где).

Comment: А с каких пор обстоятельство времени уточняется обстоятельством места? Я тоже считаю, что запятые не нужны. Насчёт пауз: обстоятельства разделены на две группы — время и место, пауза делается только после «в 1960 году».

Comment: Я бы также поставил "в мастерской тепловых сетей в г. Кемерово («Кузбассэнерго»)» на первой место после обстоятельства времени. Тогда порядок обстоятельств более логичный: время — общее место (мастерская) — более точное место (среди хлама).

Comment: О логика, ты не всегда верна!  А писателю для построения художественного образа  ты иногда и помеха...